# OAUTH 2.0 JWT How can I access request from client side to send JWT token to client application.

Tags: rest-api, json, oauth2, connected-apps, jwt

I am very new to the Oauth spec. I have done a lot of research but could not find the answer to what I should do. My task is currently my client application is using Salesforce as OAuth provider. So I simply created a connected app and gave him the necessary parameters (client ID, secret).

But now they want me touse JWT token. Where when the user login (in to their web app) using salesforce as OAuth they want JWT token (JWT access token) from my side (Salesforce Org where I have my connected app) when they POST to token endpoint.

I have gone through the documentation several times and read lots of previous questions, but can not find it. I found the code to create JWT in Salesforce and get access token but could not find when to call the class which generates JWT token.

Should I create a custom endpoint or does Salesforce allows me to intercept the incoming POST request for the token end point?

I dont know if I am approaching in the wrong way.